# Optimize index on query firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, types

I'm close to exceed the quota limit index of firebase. So i'm trying to optimize it.
At the moment, im using a tricks with object to get it with filter.
Example:
My query:

```js
query = query.where(`genres.${genre}`, '==', true);
query = query.where(`languages.${lang}`, '==', true)
```

And my object:

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    genres: {
      drama: true,
      comedy: true
    },
    languages: {
      en: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    genres: {
      animation: true,
      action: true,
      comedy: true,
      drama: true,
    },
    languages: {
      en: true,
      fr: true,
    },
  }
]
```

I didnt know the number of entries can have genres or languages. So for every case i create an new index. Im close of 200 index.

I have tried to use the comparator '==' like this:

```js
const genresSelected = ['drama', 'comedy'];
let genreObject = {};
for (let genre of genresSelected) {
  genreObject[genre] = true;
  query = query.where('genres', '==', genreObject);
}
```

So that will filter by genre === `{ drama: true, 'comedy': true }` that will find my first item, but not my 2nd item.
I would like get if property exist or not in genres / languages, not a strict check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend adding an array field with all the present genres:

```
presentGenres: ['animation', 'action', 'comedy', 'drama']
```

With that new field you can then use `array-contains` to query for a **single** specific value:

```
query.where('presentGenres', 'array-contains', 'drama')
```

This  query will select all documents that have `"drama"` in their `presentGenres` field, no matter what other values are in there.

---

Unfortunately this `presentGenres` field only allows specifying one value. There is no operations that returns where the array contains a number of values. As you've discovered, to use the `==` operation you have to specify *all* values in the array or map.

So you'll need to keep the map (and thus all the separate indexes) if you wan to select on multiple-but-not-all genres, which you'd then do with:

```
query
  .where('genres.drama', '==', true)
  .where('genres.comedy', '==', true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but im already using array-contains and we can have only 1 per query.

Comment: That's correct, which is why I explain in the second half of my answer that you'll still need the map field for queries that require multiple (but not all) values to be present.